# SharePoint not saving item for amount entered in German format

Tags: decimal, sharepoint-2013, culture

Question on SP2013. My german client will enter Numbers in list form in format - `.` **(dot)** as thousand separator and `,` **(comma)** as decimal separator.

```
e.g. 1.00.000,25 (1 lakh 25 paise).
```

I managed to convert numbers from default to german format using jquery, but I am unable to save the item.

Error while saving `Invalid number value. A number field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again.`

Please suggest.

Comment: Solved - I was facing issue with replace(). I converted number to string and then applied replace().

Comment: I doubt that German clients will enter numbers in Indian format (e.g. grouping with 2 digits after the first 3 digit group, or calling it lakh) -- and replace can be quite dangerous operator if someone enters just xxxxx.yy -- that might then become xxxxxyy